how to change the meta tags on next js with Head for one specific page?
I'm using next js 13 with pages structure. I have configured _document with a meta tags and title for global pages using Head, now I want to set specific meta tags and title for one page called "one". I tried with Head on the page but this is still using the global information.
I configured _document.js like this
...
export default function MyDocument(props) {
  const { emotionStyleTags } = props;

  return (
    <Html lang="en" className={roboto.className}>
      <Head>

        <meta
          name="description"
          content="General description."
          key="desc"
        />
        <meta property="og:title" content="Page.com - The Best Source for some stuff" />
        <meta
          property="og:description"
          content="General description."
        />
        <meta
          property="og:image"
          content="/images/page.webp"
        />
        <meta property="og:url" content="https://page.com/" /> 

      </Head>
      <body>
        <Main />
        <NextScript />
      </body>
    </Html>
  );
}
...

I'd like to add a specific title meta description and other meta tags to one page called "/one". So I used Head on the page. This works on the page for the title, but when I make the search "page.com one" on google this still is showing the General title and description for that page. When I share the link "page.com/one" this is still showing the general information on discord.
function One() {
...
return (
      <Head>
        <title>Page one</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />
        <meta name="description" content="Specific description for page one." key="desc"/>

        <meta property="og:title" content="Specific page title" />
        <meta
          property="og:description"
          content="Specific description for page one."
        />
        <meta
          property="og:image"
          content="/images/page.webp"
        />
        <meta property="og:url" content="https://page.com/one" /> 
      </Head>
...
)


Good eveningy dear
Make sure you're using the  component from Next.js in your /one page. The  component should be imported from next/head and used correctly to set specific meta tags and titles for your page.
This is how you can import that library
Import Head from 'next /head '
